# Load a local text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I need to read a file locally using javascript.
I know that for security reasons the possibility of doing this directly is inhibited.
Is there any way to work around this?
Furthermore, if I try to use the features of the File API specification, I can't get the "load" button to work if the button itself is not directly attached in the document.body. I would like this button to work even if attached to child type elements. Is there a solution for this?

Thank you very much

```
fileReader() {
    console.log("FileReader Called");

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('source-container');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
            }

            reader.readAsText(file);    
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Easier to use Node.JS and the `fs` module.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5DLoad+a+local+text+file+in+javascript

Comment: Thank you all for the reply.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. I used jQuery.get to load a file, adding to chrome executable the --allow-file-access-from-files parameter. As for the File System API, these are not supported by all browser. I will use nodeJS in the future to avoid this problem.